# aggregate row counts using foreign key entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query a table and grab ALL data in one column lets say the column we are using is `id` where their name is `NOT NULL`

```
SELECT id FROM AUTHORS WHERE name IS NOT NULL;
```

Then using the **ALL** rows from this query

I'd want to search another table called `BOOKS` using all `id` from the `AUTHORS` table, where the `id` matches the record.

Then the amount returned from each query where the `id` matches get that row count and return that instead.

Then finally aggregating the query into a result, where the `id` has a row count.

So that you end up with something like :

```
ID | Number of Entries
0  | 12
1  | 5001
2  | 1337
```

But I am not sure if this is possible?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a `join`, `count` and `group by`

```
  SELECT a.id , a.name,  count(*)
  FROM AUTHORS a 
  INNER JOIN BOOKS b ON a.ID = B.Auhors_id AND a.name IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY a.id , a.name
```

Comment: This is the one, and I now know a practical reason behind join and group by. Thank you!